# How to use java.util.logging.Handler class?

Tags: java

I want to understand this class better. (java.util.logging.Handler) Can anybody help me with some suggestions or links?
Tx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A tiny tutorial, [Java Logging API - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Logging/article.html)
- and a good example, [Creating custom log handler](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rtrb_createhandler.html).